# How to select all the occurrences of a word in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

What I wan't to know is if it is possible to **SELECT** all of the occurrences of the same word in a Java Program. I know that it is possible in Sublime Text 3 but I wan't to know if it Will work in Eclipse. And I don't mean highlight, I already know Mark Occurrences, I want it to like, select the word here is a example:

```
 public class Employee1 

 {
    private String guyName;
    private String jobTitle;

    public String getName() {
        return guyName;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.guyName = name;
    }
    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }
    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

 }
```

I want to be able to change all of the *guyName* variables to *personName* just by selecting one, pressing a shortcut that selects all of the same word then just type and change it.
Thanks :D
~Scoutdrago3

Comment: Eclipse doesn't support multi-select like sublime-text

Comment: Can `Ctrl+F` : `Find and Replace` help ?

Comment: alt+shift+t, alt+shift+r

Comment: Got/Have the solution? I'm also searching for it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yeah  - select the variable name - then use Alt-Shift-R, then rename.
Only variable names can be changed that way.

Comment: On a more global way, If you wish to change things like methods signatures : right click -> refactor.

Comment: Didn't work. I want to select all the same of the word in the class file. I have seen people do this in youtube workflow tutorials.

Comment: Thanks that is useful. Is there a way to use it like CTRL D in Sublime or CTRL J in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

just highlight the context and press ALT+SHIFT+R

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Cmd-Alt-R* in macOS with the cursor inside the word, no need to select the whole thing. This brings up a small refactor window. Select "Options" and type the new name. This works with constructs like variable, packages and so on.

In Windows I assume it's *Ctrl-Alt-R*, but if not go to Settings and General > Keys and search for "rename refactoring".

Answer (score -2):

Press ctrl + f for windows computer. Then under FIND, type what you want to find. Then in REPLACE WITH, type in what you want to replace it with. Then click REPLACE ALL.

Comment: Do you really think this is at all useful/helpful/correct?

Comment: Why is this so downvoted? This is actually the best solution for the question, as this is quite literally the most efficient way Eclipse handles replacing things such as variable names.

Comment: This is the best way I have found as Alt + Shift + R does not work on everything (like inside quotes). When I try, STS tells me:  "Operation unavailable on the current selection. Select a Java project, source folder, resource, package, compilation unit, type, field, method, parameter or a local variable"

Answer (score -3):

I do not know if my contribution will be of any help this late but anyway. In Sublime Text 3, highlight the word by double clicking on it, then hit Alt + F3. This highlights all instances of that word with cursors on each. Type over them and they all get changed, plus you could move the pointer in any direction across the words.

Comment: OP said he knows how to do that. The question is about eclipse.